# GRE absolute values multiple answer question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> [image]

This GRE question is confounding me. The answer given is A, C, D and E.

First off, if you plug in zero for all of the variables, all of the options are right. I see nothing wrong with saying $|0| = 0$. I also do not understand why B is wrong (or why it is even listed) when it is the exact same expression as the question, and would be correct if all of the variables were set to 1 for example. Why is option B incorrect?

Comment: Of course your objection is valid. I'll guess the problem wasn't from a real test. As support for that guess, note that option B is silly (and obviously correct as well).

Comment: Yeah not the real test but from what I thought was a reputable source. Unfortunately after looking through a few other questions I think the source is riddled with 'silly' questions like this.